# Is my question best suited to serverfault, if so, what's it missing?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've asked the question [Getting custom web.config sections and their contents in Powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/331436/getting-custom-web-config-sections-and-their-contents-in-powershell) which seems on the face of it to be best suited to serverfault on the basis that:

- It's regarding Powershell which I feel is a language that's more used by sys admins than developers, hence being here rather than stackoverflow.
- It's regarding manipulating server configuration, which firmly places it here

Given that only just over 15% of [powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/powershell) questions on serverfault have yet to be answered, I'm now wondering if perhaps there's information lacking from my question that would help others to answer it. Being new to Powershell and far from an expert in IIS configuration (other than via the GUI) I'm not sure what more I could add.

If my question would be better placed on stackoverflow (due to the quasi-coding nature of it) or needs more detail (because I'm a muppet), I'd appreciate any feedback either way =)

Comment: The thing that concerns me about your question is you aren't asking how to fix something, or make something work, you seem to be asking us to explain how some Microsoft tool functions internally.  Are you just curious how it works, or did you have some practical reason why you needed to know this information?  If you do need to know how it operates for some reason, then perhaps you need to make that clear in your question.

Comment: @Zoredache, I genuinely have no idea where you've got the "explain how some Microsoft tool functions internally" from...! =) What I'm asking is, in a nutshell, "how do I use Powershell to (using the WebAdministration module provided by Microsoft) grok through an IIS config file to obtain a value from within a custom config section". The practical reason for needing to do this is entirely irrelevant (as it happens it's so that some deployment scripts can tailor the values in the files based on the environment some software is being deployed to).

Comment: People miss Questions too, we all get busy sometimes. Looking through some of the unanswered Powershell Questions I'm answering a few of them, just haven't seen them before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your question is fine -- It's possible nobody has an answer (posting a question does not guarantee an answer - it just means people will see it).

Also your question is only a day old, and has only been viewed a few times.  Give people a chance to actually read it and determine if they know of any solutions.  A lot of our PowerShell gurus don't come to the site every day, so patience is a virtue (or so everyone keeps telling me anyway) :-)

Comment: I guess I'm just spoilt by the speed with which questions get answered on stackoverflow =) Patience is a virtue, but I'm in the throes of re-writing some deployment scripts (currently batch files) in powershell and want it finished *now* ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like a programming question to me, so it's a better fit for SO.

Comment: my thoughts was that Powershell is a *scripting* language with which I'm trying to query the configuration of a server (namely IIS), hence serverfault rather than stackoverflow. I'd appreciate seeing your reasoning behind thinking it's a programming question as there's every chance I'm off the mark =)

Comment: @Rob, PHP, Perl, HTML and JavaScript are also scripting languages, yet all are discussed constantly on SO. They even discuss CSS, which is neither a programming nor scripting language. The fact that PowerShell tends to be used mostly by system administrators is irrelevant. In your case the question isn't even about a system administration task. It's just programming.

Comment: To be honest you've now convinced me that my question is entirely in the right place, not your intent but hey! =) It was *In your case the question isn't even about a system administration task.* that did it, scripts which manipulate IIS configuration are **entirely** (IMO) related to system administration.